# "Sorry, but there aren't any posts by [user]." sometimes appears erroneously on BlogOverflow

Tags: bug, blog-overflow

Visit [IT Security's blog](http://security.blogoverflow.com/). As of now, the two most recent posts are by "Terry Chia". The third-most-recent post is by "scottpack". Clicking on scottpack's name in the byline of his post ("[Stump the Chump with Auditd 01](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/stump-the-chump-with-auditd-01/)") takes you to [his "Author Archive" page](http://security.blogoverflow.com/author/scottpack/), which appears to list all of his posts on the IT Security blog.

Clicking on Terry Chia's name in the bylines of either of the two posts I mentioned ("[Debunking SQRL](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/10/debunking-sqrl/)" or "[Attacking RSA through Sound](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/12/attacking-rsa-through-sound/)") takes you to [this page](http://security.blogoverflow.com/author/TerryChia/), which says: "Sorry, but there aren't any posts by terrychia yet." This looks like a bug, seeing as there are, in fact, at least two posts by Terry Chia.